# Spfx pnp people picker

Tags: spfx, people-picker

I recently found that using react picker control is using the API to track some properties
Api [azure Api](https://pnptelemetryproxy.azurewebsites.net/track)

Is there any way to stop this ?
Or any other alternative to pnp people picker ?
[pnp tracking](https://github.com/pnp/telemetry-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to opt out of telemetry tracking.

```
const telemetry = PnPTelemetry.getInstance();
telemetry.optOut();
```

See these resources for more information:

[Telemetry: Provide a way to opt-out for PnP Telemetry](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/issues/475)

[Merge for v1.17.0](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/pull/507)

Comment: Thank you so much. 
I added 
import PnPTelemetry from "@pnp/telemetry-js";
and added the below lines in onInit() ...

const telemetry = PnPTelemetry.getInstance();
    telemetry.optOut();